# Lazy loading and Telerik Reporting?

Tags: c#, telerik, report

During recent weeks I have posted a number of questions regarding Telrik Reporting which of course come back with no response.. But fortunately, I managed all the matters. Now I ma going to raise another question and hope this one had some response.

**The Question:** There is a report which displays about 455 records. I am using MVC 3, WebApi and Telrik Reporting of course. I want to implement some kind of lazy loading. I explicitly mean, display records 30 by 30 on each page of telerik report viewer. That is to say, at first step only 30 records be loaded and if the user navigates to the next page, then another 30 records show up.

Can anyone give me a tip or solution how to handle this? Does telerik support something for that?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Telerik Report handle On demand Loading on every page for the client side of course. But at first it fetches all the data form the related data store. This is what I have got after days of researches and lots of efforts on this issue. Thus, decided to share it with others as no one comes to this questions with an answer! Hope it be helpful